# Win32 API FindFirstFile and FindNextFile performance vs command line

Tags: .net, performance, winapi

We have encountered an unexpected performance issue when traversing directories looking for files using a wildcard pattern.

We have 180 folders each containing 10,000 files. A command line search using `dir <pattern> /s` completes almost instantly (<0.25 second). However, from our application the same search takes between 3-4 seconds.

We initially tried using `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` and have now tried the Win32 API calls `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()`.

Profiling our code using indicates that the vast majority of execution time is spent on these calls.

Our code is based on the following blog post:

http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/10/16/functional-net-fighting-friction-in-the-bcl-with-directory-getfiles.aspx

We found this to be slow so updated the `GetFiles` function to take a `string` search pattern rather than a predicate.

Can anyone shed any light on what might be wrong with our approach?

Comment: what are you using to do the search from the command line? Could it be that it is using the Windows search indexes to do the query rather than stepping through every file?

Comment: @Matt we're just doing a `dir /s` (have updated my post accordingly).

Comment: Sounds suspicious. I seriously doublt that "dir" uses anything else except FindFirstFile/FindNextFile as well. Maybe you misuse them. Could you provide a snippet illustrating how you use them?

Comment: @sharptooth: I have added a link to a post that contains the source code we used

Comment: @Matt dir does not use index service

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 Does [Directory.GetFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads) uses the index service? How can I know this?

Comment: compare with ShellSearchFolder in Windows API Code Pack and you will know.

Answer (score 11):

In my tests using `FindFirstFileEx` with `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` is much faster than the plain `FindFirstFile`.

Scanning 20 folders with ~300,000 files took 661 seconds with `FindFirstFile` and 11 seconds with `FindFirstFileEx`. Subsequent calls to the same folders took less than a second.

```
HANDLE h=FindFirstFileEx(search.c_str(), FindExInfoBasic, &data, FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);
```

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 the difference between using `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` and not is 0x10000 versus 0x1000 bytes for the find buffer (found with IDA). `FindExInfoBasic` may be more relevant here, though.

Comment: My measurements (W10 x64, SSD disk drive) show that FindFirstFileEx is marginally (~14%) faster than FindFirstFile. Test folder had 900K files. Enumerations took typically 1.5 sec. Except the very first enumeration, when the enumeration takes 10x longer. (For both methods, of course.)

Comment: Have to correct myself regarding the very first enumeration. After many benchmark tests I can confirm that the first enumeration (after clearing the disk cache) is a) ~3x slower in case of FindFirstFileEx()(...FindExInfoBasic, ...FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH), b) ~20x slower in case of FindFirstFile().

Answer (score 3):

You can try with an implementation of `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` I once [blogged](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/52-playing-with-findfirstfile-and-findnextfile.html) about.

Comment: Our approach is very similar to that Darin

Comment: I've tested my solution and it takes 230 milliseconds to enumerate a directory containing > 100K files.

Comment: A further speedup can be achieved with `FindFirstFileEx (... FindExInfoBasic ...)`

Comment: In our scenario we have 180 folders, each containing around 10,000 files. The split across multiple folders is what appears to kill the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IShellFolder::EnumObjects` with `SHGetDataFromIDList/IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf`.

Pro/Cons [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/91d29493-213e-4abe-91a3-36f86f72f45e?prof=required).