# Efficient way to find file with highest number in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I have a file with a fixed pattern (CONST_) and a running number (XXXX) like this: `CONST_XXXX.XYZ`.

I am looking for an efficient way to get the file with the highest number in Delphi. Traversing with `FindFirst` / `FindNext` seems to be inefficient, if there are many files.

Comment: What about searching for patterns like `CONST_9*`. If `FindFirst` finds a file, then you'll continue with `CONST_99*`. If no file with pattern `CONST_99XX` is found, then you'll continue to `CONST_98*` etc.

Comment: @TLama That would be a possible solution. But I was hoping there would be an easier approach, that I am not aware of. Something like a FindFirst combined with an ORDERBY :)

Comment: That would not be that hard to implement. The question is how much time takes the allocation for the `FindFirst` (`FindFirstFile` respectively) function call.

Comment: @AloisHeimer In order to order the file names, they have to be enumerated.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that all filenames include exactly 4 digits?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am free to choose the system, so yes I can define, that all files have exactly 4 (or in reality better 8) digits. Then I would start with 00000001. I am just planning. If there is no good way to do this (ala for instance `FindLast`), I will look for a different solution to my problem.

Comment: I don't know the performance of FileExist but you could try a binary search pattern. If FileExist has the same performance as one findfirst/findnext call pattern then this approach is a good way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is well known that finding the maximum of a list, in general, requires all items to be checked. And I believe that the most efficient way to do that is to use `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile` or related APIs. It's hard to imagine that there will be any real way to improve on the official system API for enumerating files.

That was certainly the opinion offered here: [Is there a faster alternative to enumerating folders than FindFirstFile/FindNextFile with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351288/is-there-a-faster-alternative-to-enumerating-folders-than-findfirstfile-findnext) Note that I am rejecting out of hand the option of parsing the file system by hand. I don't regard that as being very practical.

On the other hand, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782258/win32-api-findfirstfile-and-findnextfile-performance-vs-command-line#15776443) offers hope that `FindFirstFileEx` with `FindExInfoBasic` and `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` may lead to better performance than plain old `FindFirstFile`.

You may need to look for an alternative solution to your problem, one that does not involve repeated enumerations of a directory full of files. Perhaps using a database so that you can take advantage of indexing. In fact, it is plausible that the built-in indexing service could be of use.

Comment: Your argumentation, that you have to traverse the whole list, is only true if you have no ordering. I have no clue, but I would bet the implementation of FindFirst uses some kind of indexing, if available. But I think you are right, given that there are only hacky solutions, I will think about an alternative.

Comment: @Alois FindFirstFile enumerates in directory order, I believe. NTFS directories are sorted I think. But not all directories are NTFS.

Comment: I'll give up on this idea. So I wont benchmark the suggestion of @user3256855. Until someone provides data, that this suggestion is actually faster than iteration, I will accept your hints as answer. Thx

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
for I := 0 to MAX_DIGITS - 4
begin
    S := 'CONST_' + StringOfChar('0', I);
    for C := '9' downto '1' do
    begin
      if FindFirst(S + C + '*.XYZ', faAnyFile, SearchResult) = 0 then
      begin
          //Code to iterate through the results using FindNext 
          //and returning "biggest" Name
          Result := SearchResult.FileName
          while FindNext(SearchResult) = 0 
            //ommitted: handling dirs / hidden
            if CompareStr(Result, SearchResult.FileName) < 0 then
              Result := SearchResult.FileName;
          //adding recursion instead of while... should make it even faster
          FindClose(SearchResult);
          Break;
      end; 
    end;
end;
```

Warning: this code has not been tested

Comment: Your solution does exactly what my function `getRegion()` does. But that's all. (I have to your search term `4*.XYZ` added `CONST_` . In our test environment: (`CONST_0000.XYZ` to `CONST_4999.XYZ`)  CONST_4000.XYZ is found and `breaks` then. This is logical, because search term `CONST_4*.XYZ` finds `CONST_4000.XYZ` and breaks. And that is not `CONST_4999.XYZ` !

Comment: A wrong train of thought is if `MAX_DIGITS` > 4 . Then 1.loop search with term `CONST_08*.XYZ` finds `CONST_08000.XYZ` and breaks . With 2 Loop with term (CONST_8*.XYZ) it finds (CONST_80000.XYZ) and breaks. So first Loop completely useless.

Comment: @moskito-x ehmm. I have done it the wrong way round -> will correct this.

Comment: I know what you trying to achieve when you implement it correctly, it is the quickest way. It follows @TLamas comment : `What about searching for patterns like CONST_9*. If FindFirst finds a file, then you'll continue with CONST_99*`

Comment: @moskito-x Now it should be better. But the question remains, if it is really faster. Depending on the performance of FindFirst vs. FindNext

Comment: @moskito-x I'm starting with _9*..._1*, then 09*...01*, then 009*...001*, then 0009*...0001* and so on. (My assumption is the number is for instance 000353445). Could even be improved by some recursivity... Your solution otoh stops after _9*..._1*

Comment: Why you not start with : `for C := '9' downto '0' do` ?? Without `S` in `FindFirst(C + '*.XYZ',...)` . And as I said it follows @TLama 's comment.

Comment: @moskito-x My solution is starting with `'9' downto '0'` 'cause S is `'CONST_'`  in the first Iteration. Thereafter your solution stops but mine continues with '09' downto '01'. And yes, this follows @TLama's comment (if you add some recursion after the first hit)

Comment: I know but for `I := 0 to MAX_DIGITS - 4` is not necessary . `for C := '9' downto '0' do   ... if FindFirst('CONST_' + C + '*.XYZ',...)` Is good.

Comment: @moskito-x No. What happens if CONST_0 is reached in your solution (with 000353445 for example)? All remaining items are traversed - what we try to avoid. In my solution it is started again with the next chars. Just try it out. For big MAX_DIGITS and a FileCount 2-3 magnitudes smaller than MAX, I expect a big difference.

Comment: Please : The important part , look at your code there you write a comment  `//Code to iterate through the results using FindNext` you don't show us this part . So a simple loop from `CONST_9*.XYZ` to `CONST_0*.XYZ` Is only a good beginning. Show us exactly the code to get `CONST_000353445.XYZ` .

Comment: @moskito-x The code at the comment is not the important part - it is straightforward. I've added it nevertheless. I only wanted to present the idea - cannot write real code, cause I cannot test here. If one implements this as a function this could be recursively called instead of the code at my comment for MAX_DIGITs larger than say 4.

Comment: What good for is `CompareStr(Result, SearchResult.FileName)` and if you think you get automatic a higher value. Then I have to disappoint you. After Deleting and creating new files the FindFirst AND FindNext Order is now : it starts with  CONST_0060.XYZ CONST_0061.XYZ CONST_0062.XYZ and ends with CONST_4998.XYZ CONST_4999.XYZ CONST_0000.XYZ CONST_0001.XYZ CONST_0002.XYZ CONST_0003.XYZ ...

Comment: @moskito-x CompareStr finds the file with the highest number, because Findxxx provides unordered data.

Comment: stackoverflow is not the right place to set incomplete, untested code. Your code has some wrong places and therefore does not work . Look at times the description of at `FindNext()` . So what is wrong with : `while FindNext(SearchResult) <> 0` and also the description of `CompareStr()` So what is wrong with : `if CompareStr(Result, SearchResult.FileName) > 0` ??

Comment: @moskito-x cmon moskito, don't be so stingy, I had no compiler at hand - you spotted the bugs, but hey, the idea was clear. Normally I am proud of even writing one LOC without code completion. btw feel free to improve the code.

Comment: As I have already said the inner part is important, because you can make some mistakes, you only show a comment. `// Code to iterate ....`. Now you have code written so it is better. Also, your code needs more time than others. e.g. CompareStr is slow. You: "but hey, the idea was clear.": This idea is crystal clear since @TLama 's first comment. Only the implementation is not well done.

Comment: @moskito-x Ah - I see

Answer (score -1):

An alternative would be

```
for I := 9999 downto 0 do
  begin
  FileName := Format ('CONST_%.4d.XYZ', [I]);
  if FileExists(FileName) then
    Break;
  end;
```

Whether this is faster or not depends on the numbers you are expecting and on the performance of `FileExists` vs. `FindFirst` which I cannot comment on.

Comment: FileExists involves a search. That's got to be more expensive than enumeration.

Comment: @David: Agreed, I think it's definitely slower. I don't think there's a faster way than enumeration then.

Comment: This cannot possibly be faster than `FindFirst/FindNext`, since it basically does `FindFirst` for every single file individually along with a `FindClose` if the file exists.

Comment: @KenWhite: I think so too although your argument is not very convincing in itself. It really depends on the highest number, the density of existing numbers, the performance of `FindNext` and `FindClose` and more. I am not saying it is faster, but I would definitely measure it this would be my question.

Answer (score -1):

The another way is to read all occurring `CONST_*.XYZ` into FileListBox and then show the last.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
FileListBox1.Directory:='D:\samples';
FileListBox1.Mask:='CONST_*.XYZ';
FileListBox1.Update;
Label1.Caption:= FileListBox1.Items[FileListBox1.Items.Count-1];
end;
```

To make it faster, you can use a function

```
function getRegion(filestr:string):Boolean;
begin
  if FindFirst(filestr, faAnyFile, searchResult) = 0 then result:=true else result:=false;
  if result then begin
     findN:=filestr;
  end;
end;

begin

SetCurrentDir('D:\samples');
  for i:=9 downto 0 do begin
    if getRegion(Format ('CONST_%.1d*.XYZ', [i])) then break;
  end;

FileListBox1.Directory:='D:\samples';
FileListBox1.Mask:=findN;
FileListBox1.Update;
Label1.Caption:= FileListBox1.Items[FileListBox1.Items.Count-1];
```

**Update**
For test A) files were created from 0000-4999
For test B) files were created from 0000-9999
TestA made files from `0000` to only `4999` because user `jpfollenius` uses `downto`

from `0000` to `4999` = 5000 files
from `9999` downto `4999` = 5000 files

[image]

Testtable TestA

[image]

Test B

I'm shure with more files 50000 files my solution loads 10000 filenames
for example 5`0000` to 5`9999` that takes

- moskito-x  .................................. 0.345 seconds (tested)
- pure FindFirst / FindNext .......... 0.390 seconds estimated to (0.039 * 10)

Comment: This is faster than FindFirst? What if you don't want a GUI?

Comment: OP : I am looking for an efficient way to get the file with the **highest number** in Delphi Not to iterate from `0001` to `9999` with FindFirst / FindNext.

Comment: Nobody is proposing iterating from `0001` to `9999`. How do you think the file list box control populates itself? What Windows API call lies underneath do you think?

Comment: That's neither fast nor convenient

Comment: @jpfollenius : If my only one proposal is slow (0.078 sec.) ! How would you then call your solution ? incredibly slow (17.25) sec.

Comment: @moskito-x The difference is that I never claimed it to be fast.

Comment: @jpfollenius : `0.078 sec.` is fast . if you need it only once. for example : during a application start. comparison : `about 100 ms - human blink; human reaction time` .  I only want to show another way . You showed us another possibility that requires 17 sec. I have no problem with it.

Comment: @moskito-x How can `TFileListBox` be faster than raw `FindFirstFile`? `TFileListBox` is a wrapper around `FindFirstFile` and therefore must be slower.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I know the `TFileListBox` is slower. But I use this only for a maximum of 9999 files . For a `.mp3` program I need this list. My users can have 500000 or more `.mp3's`. I allow only folder with a maximum of 99999 files . So I need never longer than 0.350 seconds for the list. With FindFirst I restrict the selection down to eg Soul -Classic 9999 files and place them for disposal.

Comment: In my case, and I want it my users not expect by 300000 and more Scrolling mp3 files. To find the highest file I always write the last 3 highest filename into a `.ini` file. When the application starts, It starts with the largest file from the option.ini and search with FindFirst if it is still available , looking with FindNext only a small number of newly added files. If not with the second highest and so on . . Only if neither of these files exists , I 'm going with eg `CONST_9*.XYZ` downto `CONST_0*.XYZ` the long way.

Comment: The advantage of this list : Only one example ( with `FileListBox.items.count` and the highest filename was found, quickly and without further effort , to determine whether gaps in the arrangement of the file names are . etc.

Comment: You simply don't understand me at all. Your control is implemented with FindFirstFile and therefore is slower.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : From your Answer : `And I believe that the most efficient way to do that is to use FindFirstFile/FindNextFile` . And now you complain that `Your control is implemented with FindFirstFile` ?

Comment: You claim the a GUI control based on FFF is faster than FFF

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , No,no,no . I never claimed that . I just wanted to show a different way to find the highest file. In my time comparison it is clearly described. So my way is **0.039** sec **slower** than without GUI. Everyone can see it.