# Vista and FindFirstFileEx(..., FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that queries a specific folder for its contents with a quick interval. Up to the moment I was using [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) but even by applying search pattern I feel there will be performance problems in the future since the folder can get pretty big; in fact it's not in my hand to *restrict it at all*.

Then I decided to give [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfileexa) a chance, in combination with some tips from this question:
[Win32 API FindFirstFile and FindNextFile performance vs command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782258/win32-api-findfirstfile-and-findnextfile-performance-vs-command-line)

My exact call is the following:

```
const char* search_path = "somepath/*.*";
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
HANDLE hFind = ::FindFirstFileEx(search_path, FindExInfoBasic, &fd, FindExSearchNameMatch, NULL, FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH);
```

Now I get pretty good performance. But what about compatibility? My application requires **Windows Vista+** but given the following, regarding `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH`:

> This value is not supported until Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

I can pretty much compile it on my **Windows 7** but what will happens if someone runs this on a **Vista** machine? Does the function downgrade to a `0` (default) in this case? It's safe to not test against operating system?

I said above about *feeling* the performance is not good. In fact my numbers are following on a fixed set of files (about **100** of them):

- `FindFirstFile` -> 22 ms
- `FindFirstFile` -> 4 ms (using specific pattern; however all files may wanted)
- `FindFirstFileEx` -> 1 ms (no matter patterns or full list)

What I feel about is what will happen if folder grows say **50k** files? That's about *x500* bigger and still not big enough. This is about 11 seconds for an application querying on 25 fps (it's graphical).

Comment: PS: Your file system can have a big impact on your testing. E.g. FAT32 has a much lower limit for number of files than NTFS.

Comment: In that case you may be better off looking into [File Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: you need use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` with IOCP and only once call to `FindFirstFileEx`

Comment: side note: Use the Unicode versions of these functions, the non-unicode versions behave oddly and may not act as expected. They also usually have to have the overhead of converting to Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested under WinXP (compiled under win7). You'll get 0x57 (The parameter is incorrect) when it calls `::FindFirstFileEx()` with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH`. You should check windows version and dynamically choose the value of additional parameter.
Also `FindExInfoBasic` is not supported before Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. You'll also get run-time 0x57 error due to this value. It must be changed to another alternative if binary is run under old windows version.

Comment: Checking for Windows versions is the wrong approach, because it cannot cope with features that do get backported to a down-level OS. Instead, call the API and handle specific errors appropriately.

Comment: @IInspectable it's ok insofar as they use the version helper function [`IsWindows7orGreater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424959(v=vs.85).aspx) that said I'd question if they really need vista support considering how small a market that is.

Comment: @Mgetz: How does use of the helper functions change anything? You're still proposing to implement, what you never meant to implement. If you want to use and API in a particular way, call that API in that particular way, and handle errors appropriately. Don't use circumstantial evidence (e.g. the OS version that was the first to introduce a feature, at some point in time). This is not an invariant.

Comment: It amazes me the kind of winapi functions you find each day. I didn't knew of [IsWindows7OrGreater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424959(v=vs.85).aspx) and the whole family of them. However thank you for testing this on a XP which pretty much solves my problem. @IInspectable, are you saying it's better to handle return errors and/or downgrade functionality rather checking for Windows version?

Comment: @user6096479: You know the answer to that question already. Are you interested in knowing, which operating system runs your code, or are you interested in calling an API?

Comment: @user6096479: IInspectable offered a good approach. Call API that gives you maximum speed first, If incorect parameter error you get then call slower version API. But there is *NtQueryDirectoryFile* as mentioned in another answer. It seems to be supported since WinXP You should check this out too.

Comment: @AlexP., I think it's a good approach as well. I don't like comparing windows version as well, but i always fear crashes and without error codes. If it does not crash, then i'm good to go :) 2 calls, one normal and one downgraded to simply [FindFirstFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) seems about right.

Comment: @user6096479: and, of course, once you decide you have to downgrade, you can set a flag to tell yourself that all future searches should be downgraded as well.

Answer (score 1):

at first periodic queries a specific folder for its contents with a quick interval - not the best solution I think.

you need call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) - as result you will be not need do periodic queries but got notifies when files changed in directory. the best way bind directory handle with [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx) and call first time direct call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx). then when will be changes - you callback will be automatic called and after you process data - call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) again from callback - until you got `STATUS_NOTIFY_CLEANUP` (in case [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx)) or `ERROR_NOTIFY_CLEANUP` (in case [`CreateThreadpoolIo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682464(v=vs.85).aspx)) in callback (this mean you close directory handle for stop notify) or some error.

after this (first call to [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) ) you need call `FindFirstFileEx`/`FindNextFile` loop but only **once** - and handle all returned files as [`FILE_ACTION_ADDED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391(v=vs.85).aspx) notify

and about performance and compatibility.

*all this is only as information. not recommended to use or not use*

if you need this look to - [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) - this give you very big win performance

1. you only once need open File handle, but not every time like with
   `FindFirstFileEx`
2. but main - look to **`ReturnSingleEntry`** parameter. this is key
   point - you need set it to `FALSE` and pass large enough buffer to
   `FileInformation`. if set **`ReturnSingleEntry`** to `TRUE` function
   and return only one file per call. so if folder containing N files -
   you will be need call [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) N times. but with
   **`ReturnSingleEntry`** == `FALSE` you can got all files in single call, if buffer will be large enough. in all case you serious reduce
   the number of round trips to the kernel, which is very costly
   operation . 1 query with N files returned much more faster than N
   queries. the `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` and do this - set
   **`ReturnSingleEntry`** to `TRUE` - *but* in current implementation (i check this on latest win 10) system do this only in
   [`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) calls, but in first call to
   [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) it (by unknown reason) still use
   **`ReturnSingleEntry`** == `TRUE` - so will be how minimum 2 calls to the [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx), when possible have *single* call
   (if buffer will be large enough of course) and if direct use
   [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) - you control buffer size. you can
   allocate **once** say 1MB for buffer, and then use it in periodic
   queries. (without reallocation). how large buffer use
   [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364419(v=vs.85).aspx) with `FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH` - you can
   not control (in current implementation this is 64kb - quite
   reasonable value)
3. you have much more reach choice for `FileInformationClass` - less
   informative info class - less data size, faster function worked.

about compatibility? this exist and worked from how minimum win2000 to latest win10 with all functional. (in documentation - *"Available starting with Windows XP"*, however in `ntifs.h` it declared as `#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN2K)` and it really was already in win2000 - but no matter- XP support more than enough now)

but this is undocumented, unsupported, only for kernel mode, no lib file.. ?

documented - as you can [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx), this is both for user and kernel mode - how you think - how is FindFirstFile[Ex] / `FindNextFile` - working ? it call [`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) - no another way. all calls to kernel only through `ntdll.dll` - this is fundamental. ( yes still possible that `ntdll.dll` stop export by name and begin export by ordinal only for show what is unsupported really was). lib file exist, even two `ntdll.lib` and `ntdllp.lib` (here more api compare first) in any `WDK`. headers, where declared ? `#include <ntifs.h>`. but it conflict with `#include <windows.h>` - yes conflict, but if include `ntifs.h` in [`namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cb46ksf.aspx) with some tricks - possible avoid conflicts

Comment: Calling native NT functions (`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`) is unsupported from non-driver code. Doing so may cause the application to break randomly across versions. Please stick to WIN32 published API functions ONLY.

Comment: @Mgetz I wrote about "unsupported" in own answer. and note that is `only as information. not recommended to use or not use` - however this without any problems worked in user mode apps. say some file managers use this API direct in own code, for performance reason

Comment: given that it takes up the majority of your answer people will see it as an actual solution. It is not and should be removed from the answer. In general unsupported and incorrect information should be left out of answers.

Comment: @Mgetz - what I wrote is `correct information` - think you need downvote my answer

Comment: @Mgetz `people will see it as an actual solution` - but you not see this ? you think most stupid enough that he would not understand what is written and what is offered and what is informed ? i not think so, everybody can for self decide how interpret offer for use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and information about how `FindFirstFileEx` worked internal and why can be faster. and use or not use Nt* api.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable info. Since it's window-driver thing and my app already requires some stuff, i'll think more about it as compatibility is major point. It seems i cannot vote anything at the moment :(

Comment: @user6096479 "it's window-driver " - this is absolute false. this is user mode function. and you all time indirect **call it** because `FindFirstFile[Ex]` thin shell over `ZwQueryDirectoryFile`  . about solution - how I and write - need use notifications (`ReadDirectoryChangesW` ) instead of periodic query

Comment: @RbMm, i'll try it. If [NtQueryDirectoryFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) gives this much of performance i'll find out. However, since my clients are mostly noobs in tweaking the system, i hope it doesn't requires additional settings. What is [with special kernel APCs enabled.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543219(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: @user6096479 - i not recommended to use, try to use or not use. but what i try explain - this is *usual* user mode api, as and `FindFirstFile[Ex]`or any other. between Nt* and Zw* version in *user* mode no difference - this is alias for same function (but in kernel mode this is different functions). about your question or note about kernel mode APCs - i not understand . you are in user mode and all this absolute not related and not affected your code

Comment: @user6096479 - `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` exist in all systems (think even in `nt4` ) not requires additional settings, have better performance even then `FindFirstFile[Ex]` this is user mode api, so call it not harder or easy then any function from kernel32. but it "unsupported" in sense suddenly this disappear say in next build. near more than 17 years exist and not changed, but in case..

Comment: @RbMm, yes i read it's supported from `WinXP+` which is good thing about compatibility. I don't care about it being deprecated or anything :) i just don't want to buffle clients with settings. [ZwQueryDirectoryFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx) requires a good read and tests by me as i dont usually get that deep :) and perhaps it proves faster than combination of **FindFirstFileEx + FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH** but with full compatibility. Thanx

Comment: @user6096479 - what you mean under "settings" ? this api not require any "settings." - "requires a good read and tests " - yes, *any* api and code require this :) yes, it faster even `FindFirstFileEx + FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH`  *if correct use it*

Comment: @RbMm, about _settings_ i was referring to **ZwQueryDirectoryFile** requiring _special kernel APCs enabled._. But since i'm gonna call it in user mode as **NtQueryDirectoryFile** i should not care about settings, right? It's a note in the **[remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047(v=vs.85).aspx)**

Comment: @user6096479 - we running in **user** mode here. so all APC enable. documentation only for **kernel** side of this function. you should not care about this at all

Comment: @user6096479 - and code in user mode always  running at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL if so. this note only for kernel mode callers. for user mode all this always true

Comment: @RbMm, found seems to be working [sample](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/120136-traversing-directories-using-ntquerydirectoryfile.html) but ccan't understand one thing. Compiled as 32bit binary under win7. It perfectly works on WinXP, but on Win7 I have 25% of launches that outputs only garbage. Debugging shows that sometimes function returns without errors and saying that some data is present but the buffer content is not changed. Do you have experience of using this function?

Comment: @AlexP. - yes, i have huge experience using `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` in user mode - it of course working

Comment: @AlexP. - that sample not well design, if want good example, which work without any garbage - http://pastebin.com/9CR2iPam

Comment: @RbMm: I ported your version into user mode. It works great. it was interesting why version I found did not work well. That was simply buffer alignment. `Nt/ZwQueryDirectoryFile` requires that `FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION` (for example) is 8-byte aligned. After fixing it works fine too. But It's strange because sometimes it also wokred when buffer was not 8-byte aligned.

Comment: @AlexP. - at first code which i paste - i test and run in **user mode** - it not need to port at all. your sample - how minimum file names handled incorrect - because it not null terminated! then if use `ZwOpenFile` instead `CreateFileW` - we can use relative name! but not every time format full name - great advantage too

Comment: @RbMm: You are right. I was confused with "Zw" in the func name. Functions NtQueryDirectoryFile, ZwQueryDirectoryFile can be called from user-mode. When they are calling from user-mode they behave identically (["Using Nt and Zw Versions of the Native System Services Routines"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).